# Spaces are not matched

Tags: java, regex, space

When I run:

```
String line = "  test";
Pattern indentationPattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\s]+");
Matcher indentationMatcher = indentationPattern.matcher(line);

if (indentationMatcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Got match!");

    int indent = indentationMatcher.group(0).length();
    System.out.println("Size of match: " + indent);
} else {
    System.out.println("No match! :(");
}
```

I get no match. What is happening here? I tested the regex online at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html which seems to be specifically designed to test regex in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changed a few things, see comments:

```
String line = "  test";
Pattern indentationPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\s+)"); // changed regex
Matcher indentationMatcher = indentationPattern.matcher(line);

if (indentationMatcher.find()) {   // used find() instead of matches()
    System.out.println("Got match!");

    int indent = indentationMatcher.group(1).length(); // group 1 instead of 0
    System.out.println("Size of match: " + indent);
} else {
    System.out.println("No match! :(");
}
```

Output:

```
Got match!
Size of match: 2
```

Reasons for above changes:

`find()` tries to find the pattern in the input and gives `true` when found. Can also be used multiple times like `while (matcher.find()) { ... }` to find all matches from input.

`matches()` tries to match the complete input with the pattern and only gives `true` when the complete input matches the regex.

The whole pattern is group 0, the content of the first capturing group `()` is group 1. In this case there's no difference, because outside of the capturing group, there is only  the start of the line `^`, which has a length/width of 0.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why find() and not matches()? Also, I see that when I keep the 0 in group() I get the same result, why?

Comment: because `find()` tries to find the pattern in the input and gives `true` when found. `matches()` tries to match the complete input with the pattern and only gives `true` when the complete input matches the regex. The whole pattern is group 0, the content of the first capturing group is `()` is group 1. In this case there's no difference, because outside of the capturing group, there is only  the start of the line `^`, which has a length/width of 0.

Comment: Thanks for the information, really helpful! One last thing: you added the (), a capturing group if I read correctly from your comment, why is this necessary in this case?

Comment: @FinalArt2005: Thinking of it, in this case it's not necessary and you can use group 0 and get rid of the parenthesis. I'm used to using them, and when what you are looking for is not at the beginning you have to use them. For example if I want to extract the number from `a2b`, I would use `\\D+(\\d+)\\D+` and use `group(1)`.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for all the explanations, really helps, I'm still quite new to using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

[`Matcher#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) *auto-anchors* the given pattern, which means first of all that `"^[\\s]+"` is exactly the same as `"[\\s]+"` for it. So, to match your input, just use `"[\\s]+.*"`.

Comment: Thanks, using jlordo's answer and removing the ^ from his regex still works. EDIT: Though it's using find() now, so I guess I still have to add it...

Comment: @FinalArt2005 If you remove the `^` of his regex, inputs like `hello world` will match too, since they *contain* spaces. It his case, `^` is meaningful (he's not using `Matcher#matches` but `Matcher#find`).

Answer (score 1):

`Matcher.matches()` attempts to match the entire string, but your pattern only matches spaces and nothing else. Try

```
Pattern indentationPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s+).*")
```

instead. If the pattern matches, then `group(1)` will contain the leading whitespaces. If you are also interested in the remaining characters, then you have to add another capturing group.